# ¿Qué hacer cuando me sale un error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError utilizando JNI en ubuntu?

Tags: java, c++, linux, jni

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de interoperabilidad entre Java y C++, el programa de java recibe un archivo de enteros y lo envia a c++ como un arreglo, y c++ devuelve la media, pero al intentar compilarlo con el comando java -Djava.library.path=. nombre del archivo java( el cual es lab1), sale este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lab1 in java.library.path: /home/sofi/proyecto/
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2444)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2047)
        at Lab1.<clinit>(Lab1.java:11)
```

Y aunque intente definir el java.library.path antes, sigue saliendo. ¿Alguien sabe como arreglarlo?

Comment: Ya no recuerdo los detalles _pero_ creo que tienes que jugar con `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` indicando el so con la parte nativa para que funcione. Tienes un `so` que java debería utilizar, cierto?

Comment: Esta respuesta parece apropiada (en ingles): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825567/2437508